# How to understand the naming convention of IEEE standards?

Tags: posix, standard

I see some IEEE standards from https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/:

> POSIX.1-2017 is simultaneously IEEE Std 1003.1™-2017 and The Open
> Group Technical Standard Base Specifications, Issue 7.

So basically 3 formats of IEEE standard are involved here:

- POSIX.1-2017
- IEEE Std 1003.1™-2017
- The Open Group Technical Standard Base Specifications, Issue 7

How to interpret them?

What's the naming convention?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This document set has been ratified by three organisations. Each organisation has its own naming scheme so there are three different standards names for the same text.